# How to decide the snprintf dest buffer size

Tags: c

Since sprintf will cause some buffer overflow, I need to change all sprintf to snprintf in project. But I got some trouble as following:

```
void foo( char *a, uchar *string)
{
    sprintf(string, 'format', src_str);
}
```

The question is when the destination string is a parameter of the function, how to decide the buffer size or the maximum length of string after we change to snprintf..

Comment: You have to pass the buffer size into the function.

Comment: Call `int len = snprintf(NULL, 0, ....)`, then `char buf[len]; snprintf(buf, len, ....);`  Now at least `buf` has the complete string.  As to how much of that fits into `string` - you are on your own.

Comment: An option besides adding a new size parameter to the function is to make a `struct ustring` which holds the pointer and the buffer size. If you like you can add the string size to the struct as well which allows you to use faster functions such as `memcpy` instead of `strcpy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the option to allocate the destination-buffer yourself, you can check the length of the source string with `strlen()` in case it is null-terminatd and allocate a sufficiently large buffer for it and the terminating null-character. You could also use `asprintf` directly, if it is available.
If you do not have that option you will have to pass the size of the destination buffer as argument, because you cannot reliably determine its size from inside the function if you only have the pointer to it (unless the destination buffer is always delimited in a uniquely identifiable way).

Comment: Yes, for string I can use a strlen() to check its size, but if it point to a array, the strlen() will get some trouble.

Comment: Could you please clarify where, and what kind of array is involved here? strlen will usually handle all forms of null-terminated strings.

Comment: Hi Midor, is there any possible the * string is point to a string array, when the foo is called?

Comment: Since uchar is not a standard type I can't tell, but I would assume it is an unsigned char. However, you should know what it is. I did not recommend you to use strlen to determine the size of strings though. If it is the destination buffer, there is probably random stuff in it, and strlen will not reliably return its size. Unless you want to memset it to something like 'a'..'\0' before each call, you will have to change foo one way or the other. Either pass uchar **, so that you can dynamically allocte memory for the string (this is much like asprintf) or add a parameter for the size of uchar.

Answer (score 1):

Calling [_scprintf(...)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t32cf9tb.aspx) will tell you how big the string would be, without actually using a buffer.

Then you allocate a buffer of that size, and call snprintf.

Comment: This solution doesn't conform to the XPG7 or C11 standards. Use of the snprintf() function would.

Comment: When the foo is called, if the string is pointed to a array, it seems -scprintf() won't work. `string = &Array[len]; foo((char *)a, string);`

Answer (score 0):

You will not gain any benefit by simply changing out `sprintf` for `snprintf` if you are not able to call `snprintf` with the proper arguments. Your `foo` function needs to also take an extra parameter just like `snprintf` requires an extra parameter over `sprintf`. Since arrays decay to pointers when they are used as arguments to a function, any size information is lost.

This may be a pain in the arse if you call `foo` hundreds of times throughout your program, but if you want to make sure you avoid buffer overruns, you need to make sure that any functions that operate on arrays are fully aware of their size.

If you are using GCC or clang, you can put a deprecation warning on the `foo` function by changing its prototype to<sup>1</sup>:

```
void __attribute__((deprecated)) foo(char *a, uchar *string);
```

Then, you can create a new function, e.g. `foo_n`, which has the extra parameter for the size. When you compile your code, GCC will emit a warning for each use of the function `foo`, so you know to replace them with `foo_n`.

<sup>1. It's possible that the `__attribute__((deprecated))` part goes *after* the parameter list, but clang seems to accept it as it is shown above.</sup>